# RTP multicast client using JRTPLIB

Tags: multicast, rtp

my goal is to pick up RTP packages from a RIP (Radio IP Streamer) module.
to deal with rtp, i'm using JRTPLIB 3.9.1 (linux).

my question:
does anyone have an example, how to listen for multicast packages using JRTPLIB?